# How to adjust font size ord font alignment in col-md bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am a beginner but usually I somehow find a solution to my problem. But not this time.
I managed to code a box: Centered in the box there is the text "#01 Grunderna". This box looks nice.

**[#01 GRUNDERNA](https://mokikoki21.se/tutorials/obs-studio-tutorial-svenska/obs-studio-tutorial-svenska-grunderna/)**

However, when the text in the middle of the box is longer like "#02 Profil & Scensamlingar" then the text is overwrapping the box. Moreover, the text is not centered vertically.

**[#02 PROFIL & SCENSAMLING](https://mokikoki21.se/tutorials/obs-studio-tutorial-svenska/obs-studio-profil-och-scensamling/)**

Is there a way to be able to adjust this? I tried with font-size but it is still overwrapping the box, it is still not adjusted to the middle and the space between the lines stands the same.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge. Would be awesome to get some help.

By the way: [Here you can see the mess](https://mokikoki21.se/tutorials/obs-studio-tutorial-svenska)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHc59.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the css rule `padding: 1rem 1rem;` from `.home-service a`. And add below css rule:

```
.home-service {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Links in those boxes will be justified vertically and horizontally.

If you are using bootstrap, you may make use of the classes it provides. Check this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/ especially "Justify content" and "Align items" sections. If you want to dig deeper about how flex in css works, check this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ then bookmark it for future use:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so very much for solving my problem. It is like magic :) You should see my smile!

Anyway, I added it as additional css in the customize theme section as I did not find it in the theme editor yet.
I guess it is better to do the changes exactly as you mentioned in the theme-editor or does it not matter?

Comment: Hey Chris, I am happy to be helpful and to hear about that smile :) Btw, let me remind you of something. Stackoverflow does not work like a forum. One asks a question and gets answers. Further discussions in follow-ups are not welcome. If you have further questions, you may update your original question when it is closely related to the original question or post a new one. I updated my answer and added two links that may help you with your questions. Good luck! And please consider moving the second paragraph of this post to the original question and deleting this post.